# maven plugin on a multi module project: how to merge everythings in the parent

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, parent-pom

I'm currently making a plugin for maven  who generate a file in the target.

The issue is when the project is multi-module: I want the file of each module been copied into the target of the parent, then a special traitement merge-them together.

How can-I do it?

Comment: First what kind of file you are generating? Is it really necessary to create a plugin for it? Furthermore copying something into the parent which does not contain code nor resources etc. does sound wrong...maybe you can elaborate more what exactly you like to solve ...

Comment: It's some sort of report. There is html , and xml